# Can I do something like imsave() with text overlay?

Tags: animation, numpy, video, matplotlib, png

I am using `imsave()` sequentially to make many PNGs that I will combine as an AVI and I would like to add moving text annotations. I use [ImageJ](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/features.html) to make AVIs or GIFs.

I don't want the axes, numbers, borders or anything, just the color image (as `imsave()` provides for example) with text (and maybe arrows) inside. These will change frame by frame. Pardon the use of jet.

I could use `savefig()` with ticks off and then do cropping as post processing, but is there a more convenient, direct, or "matplotlibithic" way to do this that wouldn't be so hard on my hard drive? (final thing will be pretty big).

[image]

A code snippet, added by request:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nx, ny = 101, 101

phi   = np.zeros((ny, nx), dtype = 'float')
do_me = np.ones_like(phi, dtype='bool')

x0, y0, r0 = 40, 65, 12

x = np.arange(nx, dtype = 'float')[None,:]
y = np.arange(ny, dtype = 'float')[:,None]
rsq = (x-x0)**2 + (y-y0)**2

circle = rsq <= r0**2

phi[circle] = 1.0
do_me[circle] = False

do_me[0,:], do_me[-1,:], do_me[:,0], do_me[:,-1] = False, False, False, False

n, nper = 100, 100
phi_hold = np.zeros((n+1, ny, nx))
phi_hold[0] = phi

for i in range(n):

    for j in range(nper):
        phi2 = 0.25*(np.roll(phi,  1, axis=0) +
                     np.roll(phi, -1, axis=0) +
                     np.roll(phi,  1, axis=1) +
                     np.roll(phi, -1, axis=1) )

        phi[do_me] = phi2[do_me]

    phi_hold[i+1] = phi

change = phi_hold[1:] - phi_hold[:-1]

places = [(32, 20), (54,25), (11,32), (3, 12)]

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(change[50])
for (x, y) in places:
    plt.text(x, y, "WOW", fontsize=16)
plt.text(5, 95, "Don't use Jet!", color="white", fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Method 1

Using [an excellent answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16061699/897968) as a reference, I came up with the following simplified variant which seems to work nicely - just make sure the `figsize` ([which is given in inches](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=figure#matplotlib.pyplot.figure)) aspect ratio matches the size ratio of the plot data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test_image = np.eye(100)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
ax = plt.axes(frameon=False, xticks=[],yticks=[])
ax.imshow(test_image)
plt.savefig('test.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

Note that I am using `imshow` with a `test_image`, which might behave differently from other plotting functions... please let me know in a comment in case you'd like to do something else.

Also note that the image will be (re-) sampled, so the `figsize` will influence the resolution of the written image.

As [pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174311/can-i-do-something-like-imsave-with-text-overlay/32174837?noredirect=1#comment52241766_32174837), the `figsize` setting doesn't match the size of the output image (or the size on screen, for that matter). To overcome this, use...

## Method 2

Reading the FAQ entry [Move the edge of an axes to make room for tick labels](http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#move-the-edge-of-an-axes-to-make-room-for-tick-labels), I found a way to make the `figsize` parameter set the output image size directly, by moving the axes' ticks out of the visible area:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test_image = np.eye(100)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.imshow(test_image)
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

Note that `savefig` has a default DPI setting (100 in my case) which - in combination with `figsize` - determines the number of pixels in x and y directions of the saved image. You can override this with the `dpi` keyword argument to `savefig`.

If you want to display the image on screen rather than saving it (by using `plt.show()` instead of the `plt.savefig` line in the code above), the size of the figure is dependent on (apart from the already familiar `figsize` parameter) the *figure*'s DPI setting, which also has a default (80 on my system). This value can be overridden by passing the `dpi` keyword argument to the `plt.figure()` call.

Comment: That works great! Thanks @FriendFX for the solution. I *think* that this is exactly what I needed, I'll look into the resampling issue. The link to the other answer is also helpful for background. I'm just curious, what units are those in `figsize=(4,4)` ?

Comment: @uhoh, the units of `figsize` are [inches](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=figure#matplotlib.pyplot.figure). I'll add that to the answer. Glad it worked!

Comment: Great - but hmm... inches *where?*. The plot is about 2 inches on my laptop display, and if I open "test.png" in various graphics programs or PPT they all say it's 3.1 x 3.1 inches. Maybe it's what the size *would have been* without `bbox_inches='tight`?  I can always dial it to what I need, so it doesn't affect the solution at all.

Comment: @uhoh Interesting point. And you are correct in that if we remove `bbox_inches='tight'` from the code, the (saved) images *are* 4 x 4 inches. Through some reading and by experimentation I found another (probably cleaner) way of doing this where the `figsize` actually matches the output size (at least with SVG output since it actually stores the resolution). I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Super answer - I wish I could upvote twice! Thank you @FriendFX for your time and investigative work! fyi I've [already linked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32195525/3904031) to the code snippet you requested, good idea.